# Windows 10: no sound

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, asus-laptop

I have a dual booted Asus republic of gamers laptop, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, yesterday [the sound on ubuntu stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114378/ubuntu-16-04-no-sound) but windows was working fine up until now, now there's no sound at all and I can't install the driver, tried from driver manager and driver booster, nothing works

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is driver booster?

Comment: @CaineKiewit An auto driver downloader https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php

Comment: I suggest reading [https://superuser.com/questions/1585391#1585392](https://superuser.com/questions/1585391#1585392) to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/), I was told to reset my laptop, that solved the problem.

I don't know if the other answer is good or not, I haven't tested it, by the time I read it I was restoring my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Left-click on the speaker button circled below

[image: Windows 10 Sound Task Button]

Click on the words underlined above the volume slider

[image: Windows 10 Volume Slider and Drop Down/Up menu]

Choose another playback device.

[image: Windows 10 "Select a playback device" menu]

If the problem persists, your sound card is the next item to troubleshoot.

Comment: I spoke with microsoft support, they told me to restore and it worked, haven't got the chance to try your solution, if this problem will occur again will try your solution, I'm accepting this answer now because the problem is solved

Comment: @Lynob, I know that you have the best of intentions, but you shouldn't accept an answer strictly because the problem is solved.  If *that* answer didn't resolve the problem, you aren't really helping the other members of the Super User community who might read this Q&A in the future.  The proper thing to do would be to submit your *own* answer with the solution that actually **did** resolve the problem, and accept that accordingly.

Comment: @Run5k okay, added my own answer, I have to wait until tomorrow in order to accept it.